# Convert object to csv

Tags: c#, csv

I'm struggling to convert object to csv. Here are my classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "text")]
public class Text
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sentence")]
    public List<Sentence> Sentences { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sentence")]
public class Sentence
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "word")]
    public List<string> Words { get; set; }
}
```

Xml attributes are here due to the specification that Text object must be serialized both to xml and csv. Parsing to xml wasn't any problem however I can't succesfully achieve parsing it to csv format. I have tried to approach the problem using CsvHelper library but two nested Lists in the Text object are causing some problems.

For example I have xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<text xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<sentence>
   <word>dont</word>
   <word>I</word>
   <word>like</word>
   <word>tomatoes</word>
</sentence>
<sentence>
    <word>brother</word>
    <word>loves</word>
    <word>My</word>
   <word>them</word>
 </sentence>
</text>
```

And the desired csv output would be something like:

```
Word0, Word1, Word2, Word3
dont, I, like, tomatoes
brother, loves, My, them
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Give an example and show us how the csv should look like. At best an xml and a fitting csv for that.

Comment: Ok I have presented some xml and csv examples

Comment: Where do Word0, Word1 etc. come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using XmlSerializer

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "text")]
public class Text
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sentence")]
    public List<Sentence> Sentences { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sentence"), XmlType("sentence")]
public class Sentence
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "word")]
    public List<string> Words { get; set; }
}

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\w1\sampleXml1.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Text));
    var t = (Text)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    string[] header = { "Word0", "Word1", "Word2", "Word3" };
    list.Add(string.Join(",", header));
    foreach (var item in t.Sentences)
    {
        list.Add(String.Join(",", item.Words));
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\w1\output.csv", list);
}
```